# "tegoline" vs "fagiolini"

Tags: word-usage, regional

Vorrei sapere qual è la reale diffusione della parola "tegoline", l'equivalente veneto di "fagiolini", e se nel resto d'Italia si dica realmente "fagiolini" o si usino altri sinonimi.

Vivendo nel nord-est ho sempre sentito e detto "tegoline", e anzi pensavo fosse una parola dell'italiano standard, fino a quando non mi sono resa conto del contrario. Fino a qualche anno fa non sapevo neanche che esistesse la parola "fagiolini"...Mi chiedo come si distribuiscano geograficamente i due termini e se ne esistano altri.

Comment: Si intendono i fagiolini verdi, cioè quelli lunghi che si mangiano con l'intero baccello e si trovano pure surgelati?

Comment: Esatto, proprio quelli :)

Comment: Bene, io posso solo dirti che in generale non l'avevo mai sentito e credo che in tutto il Sud non venga compreso! Al contrario, "fagiolini" era per me universale (credevo fosse usato ovunque).

Comment: Confermo quanto dice martina e, avendo vissuto anche in Emilia-Romagna e Lombardia, ti assicuro che lí 'tegoline' non si usa.

Comment: Altra conferma per "fagiolini".

Comment: *Tegoline* (con possibili varianti nelle vocali e nella pronuncia della elle) è solo veneto; non so se sia usato in Trentino; in friulano dovrebbe essere *vuaìne*.

Comment: Per quel che vale, “tegoline” non pervenuto neppure a Roma.

Comment: @egreg *tegoline* è tipico anche dell'italiano in Friuli. Vi confesso che è solo da 3-4 anni che ho scoperto il termine *fagiolini*, che comunque non utilizzo *mai*. *vuaìnis* è il termine Friulano per *fagiolini*, e come tale non è una parola italiana.

Comment: @Bakuriu Sospettavo che *tegoline* fosse usato anche in Friuli, accanto al termine propriamente friulano. Dopo tutto il Friuli è stato per secoli uno dei territori di Venezia.

Comment: Anch'io sono friulana eppure non avevo mai sentito la parola _vuaìnis_. Uso sempre _tegoline_ anche se conosco già da qualche tempo la parola _fagiolini_, che mi verrebbe proprio innaturale.

Comment: @Sara Se non hai mai sentito *vuaìnis* **non** sei friulana. Sei solo un'abitante del Friuli Venezia Giulia come regione politica, non come regione storica.

Comment: Mai sentito qualcuno dire "tegoline" in Lombardia (provincia di Brescia). "Fagiolini", al contrario è il termine che sento spesso.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tegoline/

> tegoline s. f. pl. [der. di tega]. – Nome ***veneto*** dei fagiolini o cornetti, legumi forniti dalla pianta Vigna unguiculata (sinon. Vigna sinensis), leguminosa orticola, forse originaria dell’Africa tropicale e diffusa nella regione mediterranea già durante l’Impero Romano.

Quindi si conferma che è un sostantivo di uso essenzialmente regionale. Ma la conferma più importante, secondo me, viene dal marketing: un marchio diffuso su tutto il territorio nazionale come la Findus vende i [Fagiolini Primavera](http://www.findus.it/it-it/prodotti/cerca-per-marca/findus/fagiolini_primavera/), non le "Tegoline Primavera".

Comment: (tra l'altro una volta al mercato ho visto un ortolano burlone esporre un cartello "cornetti wireless", ovvero fagiolini senza fili =) )

Comment: ma la variante "cornetti" è dovuta alla forma a corno :S?

Comment: @martina: direi di sì, di certo non alla Algida =)

Answer (score 5):

Io sono veneta di origine, ma vivo in Lombardia ormai da 30 anni. Qui nessuno mi capirebbe se chiedessi delle *"tegoline"*, ma allo stesso tempo io mi rifiuto di utilizzare il vocabolo *"cornetti"*, per cui confermo che il vocabolo ***"fagiolini"*** è una parola passepartout, nel senso che nessuno mi ha mai chiesto chiarimenti quando l'ho usata in giro per l'Italia, mentre *"tegoline"* per me resta un vocabolo legato all'infanzia.

Answer (score 2):

Credo che un Google Ngram possa essere utile per capire l'utilizzo della parola  nella produzione scritta:[image]

Ovviamente si tratta di una parola dialettale che trova i rispettivi analoghi negli altri dialetti italiani. Abbiamo [per esempio](http://www.dialettando.com/dizionario/detail.lasso?id=49860) per il ligure "fasulèini", il romagnolo "fasulén", il molisano "fascellite", e forse anche sopratutto con il più diffuso "cornetti" anch'esso accettato ma con diffusione regionale molto differente.

I veneti sono penalizzati (rispetto, per esempio, ai sardi per cui la traduzione di fagiolino è "aioleddu") dal fatto che non sono presenti fonemi riconducibili strettamente al dialetto veneto, il che può non rendere così palese la sua origine dialettale e indurre molti veneti all'errore di ritenerla una parola appartenente all'italiano corrente.

Forza tegoline!

Comment: Siamo però sicuri che nello Ngram il "tegoline" lì mostrato abbia il significato che cercheremmo?

Comment: @martina no però siamo sicuri che alla fine se c'è un errore questo è sicuramente una sovrastima e quindi resta comunque un utile prova a favore del fatto della scarsa diffusione del termine

Comment: Giusto! Tra l'altro non mi viene in mente un altro uso, a parte un bizzarro diminutivo di "tegola".

Comment: a me sì.. il tegolino era una merendina mulino bianco di taaaanti anni fa :) http://la.pestifera.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/tegolino2.jpg

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon eh lo so c'è una vasta letteratura a riguardo....:-)

Comment: È più che tardi per correggere, ma la parola *tegolina* possiede forse *il* fonema più caratteristico della lingua veneta: la cosiddetta *l indebolita*, realizzata nella zona intorno a Venezia come un'[approssimante velare sonora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_approximant). Detto questo anche molte parole italiane sono pronunciate con questo fonema nell'italiano regionale, per cui il punto fondamentale non cambia